# Slope-change in segmented regression - interaction or "time since intervention" variable?

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis, segmented-regression

during my studies of interrupted time-series analysis and segmented regression I have come across two different ways to propose a step-and-slope change model:

One approach parameterizes the change in slope as an interaction between time and the dichotomous intervention variable.

I have also seen a different approach where instead another variable "time since intervention" is introduced, a continuous variable counting the number of measures (e.g. months) after the intervention, coded 0 before the intervention and from 1 onward to the end of the observation. 
In this approach, the post-intervention slope is calculated by adding the "change-in-slope" coefficient to the pre-intervention slope coefficient.

1. How do I interpret the interaction coefficient in approach one?
2. Is one approach superior to the other or is there an indicator when to use which approach?

Comment: Not sure if this has been answered yet but nice paper on this exact question. The second parameterisation you mention is usually a little easier to interpret: https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/50/3/1011/5937253